# Atomic selection rules and relativistic selection rules difference?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

I spent my last few weeks trying to figure out the difference between atomic and relativistic selection rules in photoelectron spectroscopy. 
I understand the fact that non-relativistic selection rules only deals with the spatial symmetry of the initial and the final states involved in the photoemission process and relativistic part comes up when we also take into account the spin-orbit coupling in the system.

Now I have a problem to understand whether the atomic selection rules and the relativistic selection rules are same? Furthermore, if we try to understand photoemission intensities from the selection rules point of view, can we think that if SOC effect (or the atomic selection rules-if they are same) is induced then it can alter the photoemission intensities in a non-symmetric way?

Would be great if someone can recommend the relevant literature. I used the book of Stefan Huefner on photoelectron spectroscopy and few other papers but could not get the relevant information.

Thanks